# Get user data by phone number by ignore dashes in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table of user like below:

```
id    name       phone
----------------------------
1     John       +1-32-5435-2343
2     Tom        +92-32-43434-233
3     Eve        +5-323-43-23234
```

`$phoneNumber = '+13254352343';`

How can I do where query to return the user that match this phone number by ignoring dashes

What I know is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone = $phoneNumber
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to replace the dashes for the comparison:

```
where replace(phone, '-', '') = ?
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the comparison value.  Don't munge the query string with a literal value.

Note:  This prevents the use of indexes.